# Software for image orientation (aerial triangulation)

Tags: software-recommendations, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, photogrammetry, stereo-imagery, aerial-triangulation

I'm trying find a software which can orient an UAV Imagery using GCPs (Ground control points in UTM Coordinates system) and Camera calibration (only camera focal length, p1,p2, k0, k1, k2, k3 and without fiducial marks).

I want this because I would like to use them into StereoTools software or any other in Manual Photogrammetry or Stereoscopy.

Can you refer some software for stereoscopy pair view?

---

I have UAV Imagery with 60-80% of overlap.

**Camera calibration**

- fx, fy - focal length.
- cx, cy - principal point coordinates.
- K1, K2, K3, P1, P2 - radial distortion coefficients, using Brown's distortion model.

AgiSoft Lens software, camera calibration parameters
http://downloads.agisoft.ru/lens/doc/en/lens.pdf

**Image orientation**

- Interior and exterior orientation.

At the end I wan to get images with Interior and Exterior Orientation.

Later I'll use the Images in a software which allows me to work in Stereo-visualization using 3D Anaglyph glasses. (The final product will be points of the ground surface with real coordinate system, I'll import them on AutoCAD).

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your question with some more details of what you've already looked at, and also on the way you're expressing the camera calibration (e.g. focal length is pretty obvious, but the other ones aren't). Also, maybe you want to explain "orient" because presumably you can orient the image based on knowledge of the GCPs.

Comment: Do you have the required hardware? Proper 3d monitor with glasses, Rat or hand wheels input device.. really expensive to get the right hardware! Unless you *really* want to plot 3d aerial photography is usually orthorectified against a DTM/DEM for plotting heads-up in 2d. We use BAE Systems Socket Set http://www.geospatialexploitationproducts.com/content/products/socet-set for stereo plotting which *might* be able to read those camera files.

Comment: OSSIM might be a capable Open Source alternative but probably not without help from the developers. They are friendly, though.

Comment: For stereo capture 60% overlap would be an absolute minimum to avoid parallax at the ephemera; for orthorectification 10% overlap between frames would be acceptable to produce a useable product.

Comment: I don't have 3d monitor, I'd like to work just in a simple monitor with 3D Anaglyph glasses.

Comment: You may find some helpful information or software through links provided in [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93326/what-lens-and-camera-settings-are-recomended-for-uav-drone-aerial-imagery-capt).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a **DJI** platform you could try "RAPID for DJI" which is a **free** Windows 10 x64 application to process up to 100 images. It will generate an orthomap, digital elevation model and on-site preview in WGS84 Lat/Lon projection. Camera calibration, image orientation, geo-referencing and dense construction all happen automatically.

The orientations can be exported in relative or real world for each image:

NAME OMEGA PHI KAPPA X Y Z

The licensed versions of the software support any camera sensor, GCP, UTM output, NDVI, DSM, Point Clouds and more. https://dronemapper.com/software_downloads

Disclosure: I wrote the DroneMapper software and service. We are offering RAPID for DJI for free forever -- at this point with 100 images processing.

Comment: is it 100 images at a time, or does it stop functioning after 100 images, and not allow you to do any more?  Are you able to expand on that a little?

Comment: no, each processing run is limited to 100 images max. so each time you generate a map you can use up to 100 aerial images for the free DJI version.

Comment: @dronemapper I was wondering if you can tell me what is the actual information that one needs in order to determine the orientation of an image taken with a UAV (not necessarily a DJI)? I have an image that was taken with a RedEdge sensor, but I am unsure how to determine its orientation from the info in the metadata.

Comment: @Perro you should be able to determine the images exact position on earth if you have the following: latitude, longitude, elevation, roll, pitch, yaw .. that will allow you to "direct" georeference the image
https://dronemapper.com/answers/uas-systems-and-photogrammetry-101/

Comment: @dronemapper thank you for your response. Let me ask you another question (if you don't mind), do you know if it is possible the extract the metadata of a pic (.tif) (taken with a UAV, not necessarily a DJI) using r? I know that exifTool by Phil Harvey is way to it; but, I am wondering if this can be done in r.  If you do, would you mind giving me some inside on how to do it?

Comment: @Perro Sorry, i don't have much experience with R. Here is a R package that will read EXIF: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exifr/index.html