# How to do Aerial Triangulation from raw aerials?

Tags: software-recommendations, aerial-triangulation

I have received 1390 raw aerial images. For the purpose of understanding I have imported 4 images and here you will see that roads are not lining up.

When I spoke to the creator of these aerials, he mentioned that inorder to match those  I need to do aerial triangulation. They have also sent me Exterior Orientation Computation Utility file having fields:

```
ID, # EVENT, TIME (s), EASTING, NORTHING, ORTHOMETRIC HEIGHT, OMEGA, PHI, KAPPA, LAT, LONG.
```

How do I perform the aerial triangulation in an open source tool or any other paid version program?

[image]

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121755/ though there is no answer there. The other two questions sharing the aerial-triangulation tag mention a specific software - Inpho Match-AT. Information generated by that program is mentioned in the ArcGIS help: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t000001v4000000

Comment: is it possible to do in ArcGIS or do i need to use external program to have an aerial triangulation?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe there isn't a method to do it within ArcGIS itself - just use the information created by other AT programs. Here's another one: http://mcmcweb.er.usgs.gov/atsys/atsys.html

Comment: is that an open source program from USGS for aerial triangulation?

Comment: That is my understanding, yes.